# Why do featuring artists not appear in the artists section?

Tags: singers, spotify

On Spotify, I have seen that the majority of the time when there is a featuring artist, they are put in the song name but not as an artist. Why is this?

Comment: As far as i'm aware, Spotify only put what the record company tells them. Split credits do not need to be reflected in the artist name, only to the angencies responsible for paying the royalties. [I'm sure this has cropped up before, but I can't find it right now]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you on mobile? I noticed that from the song itself I can only access the main artist's page, but if I go and find the same exact song from their discography, the other artists are now available when I click on 'show artists'. Hope this was the same issue as yours.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a matter of making the categorisation more clear and easy. When it's a single song feature on an album, it would be technically be creating two artist entries in whatever database is housing it for the sake of say, one song.

If it's a collaboration that spans a whole album, often the artist title will reflect that. (e.g. Edgar Meyer & Chris Thile)

That said, it's common for movie, television or video game soundtracks with multiple composers to feature in the artist heading and the soundtrack to just be attributed to Various Artists. YMMV, but say, a pop or rap song featuring another artist is best listed as (feat. Joe Bloggs).